# ARIMA Forecasting in R

Tags: r, time-series

I am trying to implement R forecast function in an online fashion. The idea is to:

1. train and make predictions for f steps ahead
2. observe f outcomes
3. re-train and make predictions for f steps ahead

In other words, if, say, f = 5, and we use 20 days to predict days 21 to 25, then use 25 days to predict 26 to 30 etc. This may make a difference. The breakdown of code I have written so far is:

**Packages**

```
install.packages("quantmod")
install.packages("forecast")

library(quantmod)
library(forecast)
```

**The data**

```
gspc500<-getSymbols("^GSPC", from = "2000-01-01")
gspcTail<-diff(log(Cl(GSPC)))
```

**Storing vectors**

```
fcasts1<- vector(mode="list", length = 10L) 
fcasts2<- vector(mode="list", length = 10L)
fcasts3<- vector(mode="list", length = 10L)
fcasts4<- vector(mode="list", length = 10L)

fore1<- matrix(NA,ncol=1,nrow=10)
fore2<- matrix(NA,ncol=1,nrow=10)
fore3<- matrix(NA,ncol=1,nrow=10)
fore4<- matrix(NA,ncol=1,nrow=10)

today<- "2016-06-24"
```

**The loop**

```
for (i in seq(from = 1, to = 10, by = 1)){

dates<- (seq(as.Date(today), by="days", length=10))

gspcTail1<- as.ts(rbind(cbind(as.xts(dates[i]),fore1[i]),gspc500))
gspcTail2<- as.ts(rbind(cbind(as.xts(dates[i]),fore2[i]),gspc500))
gspcTail3<- as.ts(rbind(cbind(as.xts(dates[i]),fore3[i]),gspc500))
gspcTail4<- as.ts(rbind(cbind(as.xts(dates[i]),fore4[i]),gspc500))


win.gspc1<- window(gspcTail1, end=500 + i) 
win.gspc2<- window(gspcTail2, end=500 + i)
win.gspc3<- window(gspcTail3, end=500 + i)
win.gspc4<- window(gspcTail4, end=500 + i)

gspcArma1<-  Arima(win.gspc1, order=c(0,0,0))
gspcArma2<-  Arima(win.gspc2, order=c(2,0,3))
gspcArma3<-  Arima(win.gspc3, order=c(1,0,3))
gspcArma4<-  Arima(win.gspc4, order=c(3,0,3))   

fcasts1[[i]]<- forecast(gspcArma1, h=1)
fcasts2[[i]]<- forecast(gspcArma2, h=1)
fcasts3[[i]]<- forecast(gspcArma3, h=1)
fcasts4[[i]]<- forecast(gspcArma4, h=1)

fore1[i]<-unlist(fcasts1[[i]]$mean[1])
fore2[i]<-unlist(fcasts2[[i]]$mean[1])
fore3[i]<-unlist(fcasts3[[i]]$mean[1])
fore4[i]<-unlist(fcasts4[[i]]$mean[1])  }
```

**Issue**

The output I am getting for fore(1-4) is incorrect, for one of them it is as follows:

```
fore1
        [,1]
 [1,]           NA
 [2,]           NA
 [3,]           NA
 [4,]           NA
 [5,] 0.0001503968
 [6,] 0.0001503968
 [7,] 0.0001503968
 [8,] 0.0001503968
 [9,] 0.0001503968
[10,] 0.0001503968
```

Each fcasts(1-4) value should be added to each gspcTail(1-4). The issue is I don't know how to add obtained forcast(1-4) values at each step to gspcTail(1-4).